# Migrate to RedisSessionState Provider

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, azure-cloud-services, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to migrate my session state provider on Windows Azure from In Proc to Redis. I am using the cloud service. I have about 100 classes and none of them are marked as serializable. Is there a way that I can mark all classes as serializable?

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type 'RuleSet' in Assembly 'XX.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Fastest way is to use regexp to update 100 source files

Answer (score 0):

You just have to mark all your classes as `Serializable`. How to achieve that is up to you, but `RedisSessionStateProvider` will complain until you do that.